# Python Selenium webscraper cannot find element despite it being on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm testing out my first web scraper and trying to obtain data from the following website: dsei.co.uk/exhibitor-list

You'll see that the scraper essentially cycles through the list of exhibitors by clicking on their name, extracting the data from the page, hitting the 'X' button and then moving onto the next exhibitor. However, after circa 15 seconds the Messenger window pops up, which ultimately covers the 'X' button which pushes a 'not clickable' error. I've therefore tried to implement a section of code before the loop that closes the messenger window before running the loop through the exhibitors but i keep getting an error message saying that it cannot find the Messenger window. Any ideas please?

Code below!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

# Initialize the web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Load the webpage
url = 'https://www.dsei.co.uk/exhibitor-list'
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load and accept cookies
time.sleep(1)
accept_cookies_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler')
accept_cookies_button.click()
time.sleep(20)

# Wait for the overlay element to become visible
try:
    overlay_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-1ecjg1h-MessageBubble-overlay-fillArea-shadowBefore-shadow'))
    )
    print("Overlay element found!")

    # Perform the required actions on the overlay element, e.g., move the cursor to trigger button visibility
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(overlay_element).perform()
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the overlay button to become visible
    
    # Click the overlay button
    overlay_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-oxvllm-overlay-small-button-button')
    overlay_button.click()
    print("Overlay button clicked!")

except Exception as e:
    print("Overlay element not found:", e)

# Continue with the rest of your code, including the loop

# Select the alphabet filter buttons
alphabet_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.libraryaz__list__item a')

# Loop through the alphabet buttons
for button in alphabet_buttons:
    button.click()
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the page to load

    # Capture the company links before iterating over them
    company_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'm-exhibitors-list__items__item__header__title__link')

    # Loop through the captured company links
    for i in range(len(company_links)):
        # Click on the company link
        company_links[i].click()
        time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the modal to load

        # Extract company attributes
        # ... (rest of your code for extracting company attributes)

        # Close the modal with retry using specific class names
        close_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'mfp-close')
        close_button.click()
        time.sleep(1)  # Give the modal a moment to close

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over all letters and get info about the companies, `selenium` seems like an overkill.

Here is how it can be done with [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dsei.co.uk/exhibitor-list"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

urls = []
for li in soup.select(".m-exhibitors-list__az li")[1:]:
    urls.append("https://www.dsei.co.uk/" + li.a["href"])

for u in urls:
    print(u)
    print("-" * 80)
    print()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")

    for i in soup.select(".m-exhibitors-list__items li"):
        print(i.h2.get_text(strip=True))
        # or get link from <a>, load the link to other soup and get
        # other data

    print()
```

Prints:

```
https://www.dsei.co.uk/exhibitor-list?azletter=0-9                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                         
                                                                                                         
'RSI Europe''                                                                                            
12 (Force Support) Engineer Group                                                                        
1MILLIKELVIN PTY LTD                     
2 Excel Aviation                         
3DBATTERIES                                                                                              
3M                                     
4 Military sp.so.o. - RUBOX Ballistic Wall Systems
4C Strategies Ltd.                                                                                       
4GD                                
4Secure                 
7STARLAKE                                                                                                
                                                    
https://www.dsei.co.uk/exhibitor-list?azletter=A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------                         
                                                    
A.E. Petsche UK Ltd              
A.M.C. SEARCH LIMITED                                                                                    
Aaronia                                     
Abaco Systems                               
ABP Technologies                                                                                         
Acacia Systems      
ACAPULKA AS                                                                                              
Accurate Nordic                                  
Accurision GmbH                                  


...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 4 problems in your code that cause it's unstableness.

1. You should maximize window to have less time actions for driver (scrolling to next element, etc.)
2. Your modal is actually in iframe, so you should first switch to iframe, click on close button, and then open first modal.
3. You should scroll to each new element to avoid `ElementClickIntercepted` exception
4. After clicking on close button for each modal you should wait for modal to be invisible, also to avoid `ElementClickIntercepted` exception.

So, after going to url, add

```py
driver.maximize_window()
```

then (I pasted only part of code where I made changes)

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
action = ActionChains(driver)

# your code

# Select the alphabet filter buttons
alphabet_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.libraryaz__list__item a')
alphabet_buttons[0].click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 'q-messenger-frame')))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-backend-test-id=close-button]').click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
# Loop through the alphabet buttons
for button in alphabet_buttons:
    button.click()
    time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the page to load

    # Capture the company links before iterating over them
    company_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'm-exhibitors-list__items__item__header__title__link')

    # Loop through the captured company links
    for i in range(len(company_links)):
        # Click on the company link
        action.scroll_to_element(company_links[i]).perform()
        company_links[i].click()
        time.sleep(5)  # Wait for the modal to load

        # Extract company attributes
        # ... (rest of your code for extracting company attributes)

        # Close the modal with retry using specific class names
        close_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'mfp-close')
        close_button.click()
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(close_button))
```

Also, try to avoid implicit waits. They are often cause flaky scenarios. I haven't changed them in your code, but I suggest to wait for something real (ex. visibility / invisibility of some element that happened after action)